# Display Api Image

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to get this image to display from an api call in php, to an img tag in html.

So far this is what i tried,

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"><img alt="User Pic" <?php echo 'src="'. $data['response']['avatar'] . '"'; ?>
```

but it's only displaying user pic, is it because the api isn't inside the php? full code below.

```
<section class="section blog-detail">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5  toppad  pull-right col-md-offset-3 ">
       <br>
      </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 toppad" >


          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Profile</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"> <img alt="User Pic" <?php echo 'src="'. $data['response']['avatar'] . '"'; ?> class="img-circle img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 "> 
                  <table class="table table-user-information">
                    <tbody>
<?php
/* Check if button was clicked */
if (isset($_POST['someName'])) {

    /* If id is empty or not a number, then don't proceed fetching data */
    if (empty($_POST['id']) || !is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        echo 'Invalid id';

    } else {

        /* Fetch data */
        $data = file_get_contents('https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/' . $id = trim($_POST["id"]));

        /* Decode json */
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        /* Display id and name */
        if (isset($data['response'])) {
            /* You should add some checks to check if id and name actually exists and are not empty */
            echo '
                <tr><td>ID:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['id'] . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Name:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['name'] . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Join Date:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['joinDate'] . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Steam 64:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['steamID64'] . '</td></tr>
                <img src="'. $data['response']['avatar'] . '"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Group:</td><td><strong />' . $data['response']['groupName'].'</td></tr>';   

        }
    }
}
?>  
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">My Sales Performance</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Team Sales Performance</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                 <div class="panel-footer">
                        <a data-original-title="Broadcast Message" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <a data-original-title="Remove this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are new to PHP cause you are breaking one fundamental rule. You are mixing the PHP logic code with HTML code. If you are a beginner and you cannot avoid writing PHP logic within the same file as HTML code at least do this: **Write your PHP code first, before any HTML and leave the HTML for the file's end**.

So, naturally this `$data['response']['avatar']` is empty above, because the $data array is being retrieved from a json_decode but "below".

So, add your PHP code above first thing, and let your HTML live below. And remember, you'll do this just because you are a beginner. Later you will learn a Framework like **Laravel, Symfony, Yii, CodeIgniter**, etc ... which is more like **the real deal** for PHP.